# ListBox item actions

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listboxitems

I have a listbox with a list of items and I want to give them actions when clicked, unfortunately when I try to double click the listbox, the action is applied to the whole listbox and I'm not being able to find tips anywhere on how to give an action to each item on a listbox.
In this case I want a click on an item on the listbox to display a youtube video on webbroswer1
So I've been asked to be less vague...I want to get each ITEM on a Listbox to navigate to a different webbrowser page. I have no more code than the one posted below...

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com/embed/ECIupNr8U-o")
```

Someone able to help?
Regards

Comment: Did you try the `SelectedIndexChanged` event? Could you show some code that helps explain what your doing?

Comment: you aren't using the value curItem anywhere... it looks to me like you will always go to the same webpage.

Comment: This is working fine when I selet curItem  on the list box. It navigates to the selected video...but I cannot add other videos to the remaining items on the listbox.

Comment: So your saying each item in the listbox has a full path to a diff video? like - `"http://www.youtube.com/embed/ECIupNr8U-o"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each item is a valid address then:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If Not Listbox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
  End If
End Sub
```